# Does the WTFPL 2 also allow the licensee to do something they don't want to do?

Tags: permissive, wtfpl

The terms and conditions for copying, distribution and modification of the [WTFPL 2](http://www.wtfpl.net/) are quite terse and to the point:

> 0. You just DO WHAT THE FUCK YOU WANT TO.

However, I'm unsure whether they are also unambiguous: Do they allow the licensee to do anything whatsoever? That's how the colloquialism "what the fuck you want to" would usually be understood. Or does it only allow the licensee to do things they actually *want* to do (whatever that may mean), as a more verbatim reading would suggest?

The official FAQ, even despite not fully spelling it out, is quite clear that it assumes the former, i.e., that the license allows the licensee to do anything whatsoever:

> #### By the way, with the WTFPL, can I also…
>
> Oh but yes, of course you can.
>
> #### But can I…
>
> Yes you can.
>
> #### Can…
>
> Yes!

But is the FAQ right about this? Or does the FAQ even *make* it right by definition, because it's been written by Sam Hocevar (who's also the author of the WTFPL 2, WTFPL's current version) and because the licensee can assume that licensor has also read the FAQ before applying the license, and thus that the intents of both, of the license author and of the licensor, is that the license shall permit any action.

**Does the WTFPL allow me to do things I *don't want* to do?**

#### Why this is relevant

Sometimes one does stuff one doesn't want to: Either because it's one's job, or because one is otherwise forced to do it, or because one sees it at the lesser of two evils, or maybe even just accidentally. If these actions weren't covered by the WTFPL, that license might turn out to be much more restrictive (and easier to violate) than commonly assumed.

One might argue that in many of those cases, even though one might not *unconditionally* "want" to do the respective action, one still *conditionally* "wants" to do it, to avoid the consequences of not doing it (e.g. losing one's job). But relying on that argumentation seems risky, and it clearly doesn't apply to unwanted accidental actions. (And while accidental distribution is something one should carefully avoid anyway, accidental copying and/or modification can happen quite quickly and is harmless under most circumstances.)

Comment: See this thread for a better explanation of the phrase and equivalents which don't include the word 'want' yet mean the same thing: [What is the neutral way of telling someone to "do whatever you want"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151622/what-is-the-neutral-way-of-telling-someone-to-do-whatever-you-want)

Comment: Your last paragraph is creative (conditional want vs. unconditional want) but I really don't see the possible risk. It would only be a risk if the rightsholder tried to take you to court and claim that you violated her license, because you did something for your job only, for example (which, according to your definition, a "conditional want" and not an "unconditional want"). I think she would have a very hard time to make the case that such 'conditional wants' should not be included in the definition of what is allowed by the license.

Comment: Yeah, @Brandin, I'm less worried about getting sued as a WTFPL licencee and more about chilling effects this doubt could cause for re-use of works I might license under WTFPL.

Comment: Already answered below but I think the chilling effect would be to the fact that it's a crayon license rather than the precise wording choice. If I am running a business and I've got the choice between using some WTFPL-licensed code or some Apache-licensed code, I'm probably going to choose the Apache-licensed, even though that license imposes more requirements.

Comment: Just use 0BSD instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WTFPL clearly gives you permission to use the software in any manner that you would legally desire, thus making it effectively impossible be in non-compliance with the license. I do not think that a court tasked with interpreting the license would partake in philosophical discussions on the nature of motivation.

This is also a good time to consider that the WTFPL is a crayon license, a joke, a shitpost. It was not drafted as a serious license, and unclear use of terms is consequence of that. Even having an FAQ is part of parodying the GPL. While it is probably safe to use WTFPL-covered software, licensing new software under it should be avoided. The “I don't care about licenses” crowd would fare much better with something like 0BSD.

> Or does the FAQ even make it right by definition, because it's been written by Sam Hocevar (who's also the author of the WTFPL 2, WTFPL's current version) and because the licensee can assume that licensor has also read the FAQ before applying the license, and thus that the intents of both, of the license author and of the licensor, is that the license shall permit any action.

No, that doesn't sound like a reasonable argument. Something is either part of the legally relevant document, or it is not. The FAQ are definitely not part of the license. While such writing by the drafter can help build an industry consensus about licensing matters, the drafter's opinion cannot tell us what other license-givers thought.

Some jurisdictions also have the concept of *contra proferentem* for interpreting contracts drafted by one party: if something is written unclearly, it may be interpreted *against* the drafter's intent. In such a context, you wouldn't be able to point to the FAQ as evidence for a particular interpretation. On the other hand, you could use this doctrine either way: either for arguing that the WTFPL allows any uses unconditionally, or alternatively for arguing that the WTFPL doesn't allow you to do things that you don't feel like doing.

Comment: What if you're forced to do something you don't want to as a result of a (legal) court or police order? Can that cause you to violate the WTFPL?